# Make hash optimize in API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

In my API, I am using like this way

```
params_hash[key1]=value1&params_hash[key2]=value2&params_hash[key3]=value3
```

Now I don't want to pass params_hash each time, is there any way to optimize this param_hash that we can call only 1 time.

I need like see example

For Example : `params_hash={key1=value1,key2=value2 }`

is there anyway we can pass hash like above in API?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: This is going through a url?

Comment: you can simply assign values directly into hash keys or you can use merge! action for this. 1) params_hash[:key1] = value1, params_hash[:key2] = value2 and 2) params_hash.merge!(:key1=>value1, :key2 => value2)